# how can i use if inline react jsx

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, syntax, jsx

I wanna use 'if' in react router for check user is login but i don't know about correct syntax:

```
const RouteWithSubRoutes = (route) => (
  <Route exact path={route.path} render={props => (
      <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} render = {props => (
          fakeAuth.isAuthenticated != true ? (
              <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/signIn',
                state: { from: props.location }
          }}/>
          )
      )}/>
  )}/>
);
```

> in this sample i wanna check if **fakeAuth.isAuthenticated != true** then redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to [conditionally render an element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) please use the [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) or a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), returning falsy value (null, false, undefined, etc.) when the condition is not met. React won't render nulls, undefined values, and false booleans.

```
fakeAuth.isAuthenticated != true ? (
  <Redirect to={{
    pathname: '/signIn',
    state: { from: props.location }
  }}/>
) : null
```

If you just want to render an element or not - then use `{condition && <Element />}` syntax, or when you want to render different components based on some condition then use ternary: `{condition ? <ElementA /> : <ElementB />}`.

---

```js
const Redirect = () => <div>Redirect</div>

const TernaryExample = ({fakeAuth}) =>
<div>
{
  fakeAuth.isAuthenticated != true ? (
    <Redirect /> 
  ) : null
}
</div>

const AndExample = ({fakeAuth}) =>
<div>
{
  !fakeAuth.isAuthenticated  && <Redirect />
}
</div>

const Examples = ({fakeAuth}) =>
<div>
  <AndExample fakeAuth={fakeAuth} />
  <TernaryExample fakeAuth={fakeAuth} />
</div>
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <Examples
    fakeAuth={{isAuthenticated: false}}
  />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine you forgot the else part.

```
 const RouteWithSubRoutes = (route) => (
 <Route exact path={route.path} render={props => (
  <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} render = {props => 
 (
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated != true ? (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/signIn',
            state: { from: props.location }
       }} />
      ) : null //here is the else.
   )}/>
 )}/>
);
```